# Set Textfield Data on click save button in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem, modalviewcontroller

I have a modalviewcontroller and have two buttons on it: Cancel and Save. There is a UITextField which is editable.
Whenever I click on save button I do save it but the text doesnot get save because when I click on the button to open the modalviewcontroller, the text disappears. Dont know whats wrong with my code.
Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

self.cancel = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
self.save = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelAction)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
[cancelButton release];

UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
[saveButton release];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(IBAction) cancelAction{
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
  }

  -(IBAction) saveAction{
 NSString *text = [textFieldBeingEdited text];

[textFieldBeingEdited setText:text];
[self setDescription:text];


[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
   }
```

I am not sure if I have to use the following code to save the text in textfield :

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
```

Comment: where do you declare and init textFieldBeingEdited

Comment: Why are you doing `[textFieldBeingEdited setText:text];`?

Comment: @jtbandes : I am not sure if I am doing correct or not. So I need a way to save it. But it helps to save the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your code anywhere that you are setting the text in the `UITextField` when the view appears.  You can add some code to your `viewWillAppear` method to set the text when the view appears, such as:

```
[textField setText:[self description]];
```

(It looks like you are storing the `NSString` in the description variable.)

Also, if this is some kind of string that could be considered a User Default, you can store the string there.  I've used this before and it populates my `UITextField` nicely.

Code Example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
stringValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"string"];
[textField setText:stringValue];
}

-(IBAction)saveAction
{
stringValue = [textField text];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:stringValue forKey:@"string"];
}
```